# Using a semicolon (;) in Printer.Print method

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I am doing a migration of VB3 to VB.Net, and came across a print functionality which used Printer object in VB 3.  By using Vb.Net power pack we are able to access the Printer object also.

Now the problem is how to pass a ";" argument to the print method
*[Code in VB3]*

```
Sub Printer_Print (tabcol As Integer, detail As String, crlf As String)
    If crlf = ";" Then
            Printer.Print Tab(tabcol); detail;
    Else
            Printer.Print Tab(tabcol); detail
    End If
End Sub
```

Tried using ControlChars.Tab, like below, but it is not working
*[Code in VB.Net]*

```
Private Sub PrinterPrint(ByRef tabcol As Short, ByRef detail As String, ByRef crlf As String)

  If crlf = ";" Then
          objPrinter.Print(TAB(tabcol), detail, ControlChars.Tab)
  Else
          objPrinter.Print(TAB(tabcol), detail)
  End If
End Sub
```

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Printer.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.write) instead if you don’t want to get an automatic line feed.

However, this should at best be a short-lived transitional solution. The compatibility pack is not really good .NET code and it doesn’t integrate logically with the rest of the code. Instead, [switch to using the proper .NET functionalities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) in the long run. They work *completely* different but are vastly more powerful, and only slightly more complex to use.

Comment: That does work. Thanks. But not sure why Tab(tabcol) behaves differently here. When i do Tab(20) i was expecting it to absolute position next char at 20, but it appears to print 20 white spaces. In other words "TAB" behaves like "SPC" (White space). Can you please suggest.

Comment: @Anoop [According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8twfh28(v=vs.71)) this should more or less work – but those functions have no real place in .NET since they rely on legacy hardware interfaces which simply don’t exist anymore and have to be emulated. I can imagine that the emulator doesn’t work properly. I can’t say any more since I’ve never used these functions.